# Ajax file download and store

Tags: ajax, download, save

i have been searching all over the internet, for the past few days and could not find appropriate solution.

I am trying to request file through AJAX, and store it on the server for later use.

Here is my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax  ({
    type: "GET",
    url: webApiUrl+"file/"+fileId+"?account="+account,
    dataType: 'arraybuffer',
    async: false,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + authenticationToken
    },
    complete: function (data1){

    }

});
```

I am fairly new to AJAX calls, so the question is how do I store this file, it can be image or Audio file. If i understood so far, i guess i receive binary data of the file, and have just to store the file.

Here is one response header received:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=download(2)_digimarc_S5.jpg 
Content-Length:34508
Content-MD5:NPZuT9bGSLIfqk9TThIFJA==
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Mon, 29 Jun 2015 10:04:20 GMT
Expires:-1
Last-Modified:Mon, 29 Jun 2015 00:40:23 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319  
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET 
X-RateLimit-Long:Limit=2500; Remain=2497; Expires=3599
X-RateLimit-Short:Limit=250; Remain=247; Expires=59
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that jQuery still does not support HTML5

For this use Ajax Transport plugin

Ajax transport creates new XMLHttpRequest and passes all the received data back to the jQuery.

Refer : [Ajax Transport Example](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer vijay, but what after that? How to save it as file on the server for later use? I see that i can get all the necessary information from the AJAX call, the binary data,content-type, filename ... but the problem i am facing is the saving of this data, into a file. For ex. the example, i would want to save the image as download(2)_digimarc_S5.jpg on the server. I have seen lot of examples of providing link to user and all that, but i dont want to do that, i just want to save the file on the server.

Comment: OK borce, for what reason you give as async : false

Comment: just because i can not and dont have time to deal right now with async calls, i know it defeats the purpose of ajax calls, but at the moment, i need to wrap up this project, and move on. I plan to make all the calls sync at later point, but right now have lot of other things to finish, so easiest is to make the calls sync. And also i dont know if DataType is correct.

Comment: the project it is not for a client, it is for my own company, so at the moment, instead of rethinking and learning everything about ajax, i found it easiest to make the calls sync and make the objective.

Comment: if you didn't care about codes and matters only functionallity.. try **ajaxupload.js** .[Example](http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader/examples.php?e=1)

Comment: true i dont care about codes, just functionality, but i am looking for ajax download and save file on server, not upload.